# protobuf syntax error during cross compiling

Tags: arm, protocol-buffers, cross-compiling

I built my project which has protobuf as a dependency in arm cpu and intel cpu(cross compile arm) both.
In arm pc doesn't have problem to build, but in the crosscompile environment it has syntax error.

```
../usr/bin/protoc: Syntax error: ")" unexpected
```

In the proto file, it doesn't have any "(" or ")" characters.

Could I build a project using a dependency package which is compiled by the cross compiler?

Answer (score 1):

This kind of cryptic error message is often caused by an attempt to execute a program compiled for another architecture.

The build process does provide a `protoc` executable, but if you are cross-compiling, is will be build for your target architecture, not the `x86_64` one.

Since the build process will at one point attempt using the `protoc` executable it produced for its own purpose, it will fail executing it on your `x86_64`system because of the architecture mismatch.

You can check by executing the command `file ../usr/bin/protoc`. You should ideally see `ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV)` in the output, but should see `ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV)` or an `AArch64` equivalent in the case I would be right.

When cross-compiling Protocol buffer, you need to make sure you have already built/installed `protoc` for `x86_64` first, then use the following option when configuring for cross-compiling:

```
./configure --with-protoc=protoc
```

You will have to replace `protoc` by  the location of the `x86_64` protoc version in the case it would not be in your path.
 See the [Note for cross-compiling](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/src/README.md) section of the Protocol Buffer documentation.

Comment: @kangfox: did this help ?